# Use different packages for different builds iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a package named assets where I store my database and media files. I want to publish my application and use source control, but I need to use different assets for each publication. How can I achieve that in xcode ?

Answer (score 0):

Create different Targets for the builds you need (right click on a target and duplicate it is the easiest way ) then change the Target Membership of the assets required for the specific targets you need ( target membership can be seen on the right hand pane when you select an asset and this will give you the ability to checkbox assets against the Targets )